# PHP Table issues

Tags: php

I'm having issues printing an HTML table in PHP. The result looks like this https://gyazo.com/308b82e1cfe18b62167bd9bda0aa830c

My code is:

```
<?php
    $os = $_POST['os'];
    $numCopies = $_POST['numCopies'];

    $subTotal = $numCopies * 35.00;
    $salesTax = $subTotal * 0.07;


    $totalCost = $subTotal + $salesTax + $shippingAndHandling;



    print("<table border =\"2\"><tr><td>Operating System</td><td>$os</td></tr>");
    print("<tr><td>Number of copies</td><td>$numCopies</td><td>");

    print("<tr><td>Sub-total</td><td align=\"right\">$".number_format($subTotal, 2)."</td></tr>");

    print("<tr><td>Sales tax</td><td align=\"right\">$".number_format($salesTax, 2)."</td></tr>");

    print("<tr><td>Shipping and handling</td><td align=\"right\">$".number_format($shippingAndHandling, 2)."</td></tr>");

    print("<tr><td>TOTAL:</td><td align=\"right\">$".number_format($totalCost, 2)."</td></tr></table>");

?>
```

I'm not really sure how to properly display this table. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check your error log?

Answer (score 0):

Use echo instead of print:

```
$subTotal = $numCopies * 35.00;
$salesTax = $subTotal * 0.07;

$totalCost = $subTotal + $salesTax + $shippingAndHandling;

echo "<table border =\"2\"><tr><td>Operating System</td><td>$os</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Number of copies</td><td>$numCopies</td><td>";
echo "<tr><td>Sub-total</td><td align=\"right\">$".number_format($subTotal, 2)."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Sales tax</td><td align=\"right\">$".number_format($salesTax, 2)."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Shipping and handling</td><td align=\"right\">$".number_format($shippingAndHandling, 2)."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>TOTAL:</td><td align=\"right\">$".number_format($totalCost, 2)."</td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: After the changes, I'm still running into the same issue.

https://gyazo.com/008b57cd216ca4efad45cef9dba5078a

Comment: Where are you trying to run it? It seems like the PHP isn't getting interpreted. Do you have any opening `<?php` tag?

Comment: I have a seperate HTML document, that links to the php. See images


-The HTML - https://gyazo.com/6a29086b87d17ba55d19cc8bcfc44c2d

-The PHP -  https://gyazo.com/ef0f44b37ea5ce8379cef2d1e213a817

Comment: try running it on incognito

Answer (score 0):

You wrongly written `</td>`instead of `</tr>` here

```
  print("<tr><td>Number of copies</td><td>$numCopies</td></tr>");
```

Also print after making complete table

Like  this:

```
 <?php
   $os = $_POST['os'];
   $numCopies = $_POST['numCopies'];

   $subTotal = $numCopies * 35.00;
   $salesTax = $subTotal * 0.07;


   $totalCost = $subTotal + $salesTax + $shippingAndHandling;

  $str = "";

  $str .= "<table border ='2'><tr><td>Operating System</td><td>$os</td></tr>";
  $str .="<tr><td>Number of copies</td><td>$numCopies</td></tr>";

  $str .="<tr><td>Sub-total</td><td align='right'>$".number_format($subTotal, 2)."</td></tr>";

  $str .="<tr><td>Sales tax</td><td align='right'>$".number_format($salesTax, 2)."</td></tr>";

  $str .="<tr><td>Shipping and handling</td><td align='right'>$".number_format($shippingAndHandling, 2)."</td></tr>";

  $str .="<tr><td>TOTAL:</td><td align='right'>$".number_format($totalCost, 2)."</td></tr></table>";
```

Echo at last

```
 echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite tricky to format an html content inside `<?php ?>`. You should put the html content outside the `<?php ?>` instead

```
<?php
    $os = $_POST['os'];
    $numCopies = $_POST['numCopies'];

    $subTotal = $numCopies * 35.00;
    $salesTax = $subTotal * 0.07;

    $totalCost = $subTotal + $salesTax + $shippingAndHandling;

?>
<table border = "">
    <tr>
        <td>Operating System</td>
        <td><?php $os ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number of copies</td>
        <td>$numCopies</td>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub-total</td>
        <td align="right">$<?php echo number_format($subTotal, 2) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sales tax</td>
        <td align="right">$<?php echo number_format($salesTax, 2); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shipping and handling</td>
        <td align="right">$<?php echo number_format($shippingAndHandling, 2); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TOTAL:</td>
        <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Quick follow up; what you posted worked.

The data pulls into the table like this - https://gyazo.com/ad903ec4221dc7234b9827628c6a522c

Think it's something wrong with my php config?

Comment: Yeah it seems like the `$_POST['os']` and `$_POST['numCopies']`doesn't have a value after all. And for the EDIT: `<td>$numCopies</td>` should be like this `<td><?php echo $numCopies; ?></td>`  ..

Comment: Ah and take note. Your file extension should be `.php` not `.html`. Otherwise the value will not really display..